# Auth0 Angular - 401 when trying to get/update the profile with auth0.client

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0, auth0-lock

I am using Auth0 alongside an Angular application. I am hitting the Management API of Auth0 to update the profile metadata with the following methods which I got from Auth0 documentation:

```
  public getProfile(cb): void {
    if (!this._accessToken) {
      throw new Error('Access Token must exist to fetch profile');
    }

    const self = this;
    this.auth0.client.userInfo(this._accessToken, (err, profile) => {
      if (profile) {
        self.userProfile = profile;
      }
      cb(err, profile);
    });
  }

  public updateProfile(profileChanges : ProfileUpdate): Observable<any>  {
    console.log(this.userProfile);
    var url = 'https://APP.auth0.com/api/v2/users/' + this.userProfile.sub;
    var data = {
      user_metadata: {
        firstName: profileChanges.firstName,
        lastName: profileChanges.lastName,
        telephone: profileChanges.telephone
      }
    };

    return this.http.patch(url, data);
  }
```

Since I will have some additional custom logic firing inside of the JwtInterceptor, I wrote a custom one like so instead of using the HttpClient from Auth0 extensions:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
      if (currentUser) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
          }
        });
      }
      return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

This ends up with 401 against the Management API every time I try to get or post a profile update. The authentication and authorization mechanisms however work without issue and I can log in and log out just fine. I was trying to switch around the tokens to idTokens instead and making sure that I don't miss any permissions inside of Auth0 dashboard but I don't see anything. Any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I assume that you're trying to call the Auth0 Management API with the same access token that you use for your own backend/API. That won't work due to wrong token audience and scopes. The Management API needs to be called with a token explicitly issued for that.

Note though that usually the end user would not call that management API himself, but that would be a call from your backend to the Management API, where your backend would fetch the access token for it via [Client Credentials Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials) (M2M / Machine to Machine).

An SPA (Single Page Application) has no way to store the client credentials securely to execute such a client credentials grant.

See

https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens

[image]

Comment: That seems like an overkill, according to the tutorials I watched on pluralsight this should be the approach used, directly from the SPA, also this is the approach I see in Auth0 documentation (from which the above was taken). Why would they even provide an API like this.auth0.client.userInfo if it wasn't meant to be working?

Comment: Can you put the links to Pluralsight and Auth0 docs that you are referring to? 
The access token must definitely have the correct `audience` set in it (`aud` claim), which should be the Auth0 userinfo endpoint. In other words, in the authorize request you're sending out, is the audience set to `https://YOUR_TENANT.auth0.com/api/v2/`? Decode the access token on jwt.io and see if this is the case. Otherwise the access token is not meant for this API endpoint. Note that fetching/reading a userinfo profile isn't the same as *writing* userinfo, these are different permissions.

Comment: For one this: https://www.udemy.com/angular2-advanced/learn/lecture/6375752#overview but it was also visible on auth0 website a month ago but apparently it changed now completely so I guess this will have to be rewritten.